# Value of numeric_limits<streamsize>::max() in c++

Tags: c++, byte, numeric-limits

While using `cin.ignore()` in c++, it takes an argument of number of characters to consume until the delimiter occurs. 
Most often I have observed the following to be used `cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');`

I was curious to know the value of `numeric_limtis<streamsize>::max()` so I just outputted its value and it came to be a humongous value of 9223372036854775807 .
If it represents the number of characters, then it can be considered in bytes and if that's true, isn't this a very large value exceeding my HDD space.

Can someone please tell me what it actually is and why such a large value ?

Comment: It's the absolute maximum number of characters that the stream buffer can **theoretically** support. It's effectively a way of saying "ignore characters without limit, until we see the delimiter".

Comment: Also, that humongous number is precisely `2^63 - 1`, which is the maximal value of a signed 64bit integer.

Comment: note that `streamsize` is just a typedef. Afaik also with containers you would run into problems before you push `numeric_limits<size_t>::max()` elements. I think those are just telling you what the types can support, while you seem to care about what your physical hardware can support

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> isn't this a very large value exceeding my HDD space.

That's exactly the purpose of this value. You want to skip as many char as possible. In fact, this value does indicate *infinite*, since the [count test is disabled for this value](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore):

> count characters were extracted. This test is disabled in the special
>   case when count equals std::numeric_limits< std::streamsize >::max()

Answer (score 0):

`numeric_limtis<streamsize>::max()` gives you the maximum value an object of `streamsize` can hold.  This isn't actually how many characters can be in the buffer, it's just what the type the buffer uses supports.  If you had a big enough machine with enough memory then you could get 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 characters in the buffer.